# Word: Autonumbering IF other column not empty

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, numbering, column

I am at a little loss currently.
I simply want word (MacOSX) to auto number in column two (See picture attached) if there is text in column three.

My Table is basically one line with four columns which span across multiple (if not more than 20+ pages). Might have not been the smartest idea, but this is how I have to live with it now.

How would I go about trying to automatically number in **column 2** ONLY IF there is text present in **column 3**?

I really hope to get some help here.

Thanks.

PICTURE OF TABLE
[image]

*Obviously sorry about the redactions, but this is just to fulfill my duty to keep people anonymous. Thanks.*

Comment: Look into the ListNum field. This should be a table with four columns. You should start a new row each time you have a new speaker.